# ID with ACCP implies atomic domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, axiom-of-choice

PID implies Atomic domain or ID with Ascending chain condition for principal ideals. I know proof using DC. But are these facts really dependent on DC?

Comment: What is an atomic domain? And what is an ID?

Comment: @AsafKaragila An ID is an integral domain. An atomic domain is a domain such that every element is a finite product of irreducible elements.

Comment: @Sushil I understood your question, but I have to say that it is a little cryptic. Maybe you should say what is the proof you know. I suspect that your question is related to the characterization of Noetherian posets ("satisfying ACC" is equivalent on "every non-empty subset has a maximal element"): I have totally no idea if this is equivalent on dependent choice (I have no familiarity with model theory), but it seems to be quite reasonable.

Comment: Yes sorry forget to mention. I thought these are standard terminology. But these mean same as @Crostul pointed out

Comment: @Crostul I know two proof one as you mentioned but this also uses Dependent choice